# C++ virtual function behavior

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am doing some exercise on my understanding. on compiling below code I get Derived::disp() called and which in turn calls non-virtual function "Print".

My question is why Derived class "Print"version is called instead of Base print version even "Print" is not virtual.

```
class Base
{
public:
     void print(){
        cout<<"Base::Print()\n";
    }
 virtual void disp(){
    cout<<"Base::Disp()\n";
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void print(){
        cout<<"Derived::Print()\n";
    }
    void disp(){
    cout<<"Derived::Disp()\n";
    print();
    }
};

void main()
{
    Base *pB = new Derived();

    pB->disp();
}
```

output:
Derived::Disp()
Derived::Print()

Comment: Should that be `int main`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a call to a NON-virtual function inside a (virtual or non-virtual) member function, the member function of that class is called.

If you were to call `pB->print()` in main, it would call `Base::Print`. But as it stands, the `pB->Disp()` calls `Derived::Disp()` which calls `Derived::Print` on the basis that it is called from inside the `Derived` class.

Answer (score 1):

Within the body of a non-static member function the keyword `this` has the type of pointer to the object of the class type for which the function is called.

If a virtual function is called for a derived class then `this` has the type of the pointer of this class.

Inside member functions access to class members looks for example in the context of your program like

```
( *this ).print();
```

where `this`  has type `Derived *`.

Thus member function `print` of this class is called.

Comment: what happens if base class NON-virtual function calls a virtual function of base

Comment: @Raj  Its virtual function will be called because the table of pointers to virtual functions contains a pointer to its own function.